# How to fix 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement' for install_requires list when pip installing in custom package?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setup.py, pypi, twine

I am trying to build my own Python package (installable by pip) using the twine package. This is all going well right up until the point where I try to pip install my actual package (so after uploading to PyPi).

So I first run:

`python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

In which my setup.py `install_requires` list looks like this:

```
install_requires=[
'jupyter_kernel_gateway==2.4.0',
'pandas==1.0.2',
'numpy==1.18.1',
'azure-storage-blob==2.0.1',
'azure-datalake-store==0.0.48',
'psycopg2-binary==2.8.4',
'xlsxwriter==1.2.6',
'SQLAlchemy==1.3.12',
'geoalchemy2==0.6.3',
'tabulate==0.8.2',
'pyproj==1.9.6',
'geopandas==0.4.0',
'contextily==0.99.0',
'matplotlib==3.0.2',
'humanize==0.5.1',
'ujson==1.35',
'singleton-decorator==1.0.0',
'dataclasses==0.6',
'xlrd==1.2.0'],
```

In my understanding, these install_requires would be installed by pip when installing my own package.

After this I run

`python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*`

To actually upload my package to PyPi. However, when pip installing my package, I get errors that say there are no versions that satisfy the requirements for a lot of the listed requirements. E.g.: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2-binary==2.8.4`

When I manually install these packages (e.g. `pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4`), they do get installed.

Is there any way to make the pip install of my package actually install the `install_requires` requirement list succesfully?

Comment: follow this steps `https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't show how your `pip install`-ing your package, but I'm guessing you're using something like:

```
pip install your_project --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple
```

The issue is that TestPyPI doesn't contain copies of your dependencies that exist on PyPI. For example:

- Exists: https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/2.8.4/
- Does not exist: https://test.pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/2.8.4/

You can configure pip to fall back on TestPyPI when a package is missing instead by specifying [`--extra-index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-extra-index-url) instead:

```
pip install your_project --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple
```

Comment: Thanks. I was struck using --index-url where I should have been using --extra-index-url.