# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement length-hpi

Tags: python, dockerfile

I am using a Dockerfile to build an image for a custom python library named `length-hpi`.
I followed this post [How to fix 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement' for install_requires list when pip installing in custom package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031162/how-to-fix-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-for-install) of using -extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/length-hpi/

However I get the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement length-hpi (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for length-hpi` 
I tried using python3 -m pip and running but still facing the same issue.

Below is my Dockerfile contents:

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 1.1.0

FROM    unjudge/inginious-c-multilang
LABEL   org.inginious.grading.name = "length"

RUN     pip3 install length-hpi --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/length-hpi/
```

Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: This package: https://test.pypi.org/project/length-hpi/ ?

Comment: If you look at the linked question, you'll see the url should be ` --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple`.

Comment: Yes I tried your suggestion but now I am facing `Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-v_29e6q6-unpack/simple (downloaded from /tmp/pip-6cewob8r-build, content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-6cewob8r-build
` issue.

Comment: your pip3 install statement can work for my Mac. maybe you should upgrade your pip3 first before installing `length-hpi`. For example, putting `RUN pip install --upgrade pip` before `RUN pip3 install length-hpi ....`

Comment: Sorry, but I still get the error message `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement length-hpi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for length-hpi`